# pad smallint with 0s in DB2 sql for z/os

Tags: sql, database, db2, zos

is there any way to pad 0's to smallint in DB2 for mainframe z/OS. I am not writing any program but running query directly on DB2 QMF.

Field definition:

```
Column Name  Col type length
some_column  Smallint  2

 some_column     result
 -----------     ------
  288         ==>  0288
  88          ==>  0088
  1224        ==>  1224
```

Comment: This is general idea on most systems: `right('000'+cast(c as varchar(10)), 4)`

Comment: @shawnt00, will that really work with arbitrary numbers? (Sometimes 1 digit, sometimes 2 etc...)

Comment: I get following error: i am running this query directly on DB2 and not using any program. I replaced c with column name         
 DSNT408I SQLCODE = -171, ERROR:  THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF
          ARGUMENT 1 OF + IS INVALID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of DB2 for z/OS there's a function `DIGITS()` that does exactly what you need.

Comment: DIGITS() function will not and is not working here because the function returns a 5 length string if argument is small integer . The argument in my case is small int.  I am getting result as  00360   00288  and I want  0360 0288

Comment: @AshishSriAshish So take only the right-most 4-character substring.